# Optimize finding diameter of binary tree in Python

Tags: python, tree

I'm wondering how I can optimally find the diameter (or longest path between any two leaf nodes) of a binary tree. I have the basic solution below, but the second solution requires passing pointers. How can I do something like this in Python?

```
def find_tree_diameter(node):
    if node == None:
        return 0

    lheight = height(node.left)
    rheight = height(node.right)

    ldiameter = find_tree_diameter(node.left)
    rdiameter = find_tree_diameter(node.right)

    return max(lheight+rheight+1, ldiameter, rdiameter)

def find_tree_diameter_optimized(node, height):
    lheight, rheight, ldiameter, rdiameter = 0, 0, 0, 0

    if node == None:
#        *height = 0;
        return 0

    ldiameter = diameterOpt(root.left, &lheight)
    rdiameter = diameterOpt(root.right, &rheight)

#    *height = max(lheight, rheight) + 1;

    return max(lh + rh + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter));
```

Comment: Sorry . . . What do you mean by "longest path between any two leaf nodes"?  Do you mean the depth of the deepest node plus the depth of the second deepest node?

Comment: Also, what is `&lheight`?  Are you coping this code from C/C++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python supports multiple return values, so you don't need pointer arguments like in C or C++. Here's a translation of the code:

```
def diameter_height(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0, 0
    ld, lh = diameter_height(node.left)
    rd, rh = diameter_height(node.right)
    return max(lh + rh + 1, ld, rd), 1 + max(lh, rh)

def find_tree_diameter(node):
    d, _ = diameter_height(node)
    return d
```

The function `diameter_height` returns the diameter and the height of the tree, and `find_tree_diameter` uses it to just compute the diameter (by discarding the height).

The function is O(n), no matter the shape of the tree. The original function is O(n^2) in the worst case when the tree is very unbalanced because of the repeated height calculations.

Comment: Hi I think `diameter_height()` should return `max(lh + rh, ld, rd), 1 + max(lh, rh)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Python 3 solution

```
def findDepth(root):

    if root is None:
        return 0

    return 1 + max(findDepth(root.left), findDepth(root.right))

class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:

        if root is None:
            return 0

        left = findDepth(root.left)
        right = findDepth(root.right)

        ldia = self.diameterOfBinaryTree(root.left)
        rdia = self.diameterOfBinaryTree(root.right)


        return max(left+right, max(ldia, rdia))
```